# requesting data from exteneral json file in the same folder of the site and use it in html page bu jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I jave this .json file

```json
{ 
    "Link": "test1",
    "Code": "test2" 
}
```

I want to use it in my HTML page by [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)
or anything if works

when I use this function like this

```
var jqxhr = jQuery.getJSON('json.json', function () {
        console.log('success');
    })
    .done(function () {
        console.log('second success');
    })
    .fail(function () {
        console.log('error');
    });
```

in console :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/json.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https, chrome-untrusted.

> error

> json.json:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: `$.getJSON()` is perfect for this. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: wait me I'll write the problem I'm facing

Comment: check the question

Comment: That error is because you cannot make AJAX requests to the local file system due to security restrictions in place in modern browsers. From the path in the error it looks like you've already installed XAMPP, so just run the code through the webserver instead and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is blocking the json request due to CORS restriction, and it's not possible to fix it without at least a local server running.

Try this to test your site: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

With a local server, the browser will recognize the JSON file with the same origin.

To know more about CORS:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS